# Using @Inject with OSGi Services with Eclipse4 Dependency Injection

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, e4

I have 3 plugins

- `de.vogella.osgi.quote` (Defines the interface IQuoteService)
- `de.vogella.osgi.ds.quoteservice` (Defines the implementation
  QuoteService)
- `test` (My actual application)

I'm registering `QuoteService` as an **OSGi** Service using a Service-Component entry in the manifest, basically following the instructions [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html).

I'm trying to get this service to be injected in my application, using this code:

```
package test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

import de.vogella.osgi.quote.IQuoteService;


public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
    @Inject
    IQuoteService quoteService;

    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "test"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static Activator plugin;


    public Activator() {
    }

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
        InjectorFactory.getDefault().inject(this, null);
        System.out.println(quoteService.getQuote());
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

}
```

When I run this I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "Activator.quoteService": no actual value was found for the argument "IQuoteService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:84)
    at test.Activator.start(Activator.java:45)
```

I know that my service is registered, because I can access it with this code:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;

    ServiceReference serviceReference = context.
              getServiceReference(IQuoteService.class.getName());
    quoteService = (IQuoteService) context.
              getService(serviceReference); 

    //InjectorFactory.getDefault().inject(this, null);
    System.out.println(quoteService.getQuote());
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? According to some source such as [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection), it should be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supplying an `IEclipseContext` to the injection code so it has no way to resolve the service (there is no fallback if you do not supply a context).

In an Activator you can access the OSGi service context with:

```
IEclipseContext serviceContext = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(bundleContext);
```

Use `ContextInjectionFactory` rather than `InjectorFactory`:

```
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(this, serviceContext);
```